# python code running well locally but not in AWS EC2(ubuntu)

Tags: python, json, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, python-requests

I'm trying to parse a website with the requests module on AWS EC2.

```
import requests
some_data = {'a':'',
             'b':''}
with requests.Session() as s:
    result = s.post('http://website.com',data=some_data)
    print(result.text)
```

The page is responding as below:

```
{
    "arrangetype":"U",
    "list": [
        {
            "product_no":43,
            "display_order":4,
            "is_selling":"T",
            "product_empty":"F",
            "fix_position":null,
            "is_auto_sort":false
        },
        {
            "product_no":44,
            "display_order":6,
            "is_selling":"T",
            "product_empty":"F",
            "fix_position":null,
            "is_auto_sort":false
        }
    ],
    "length":2
}
```

so I did as below thanks to Roadrunner's help([parsing and getting list from response of get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738393/parsing-and-getting-list-from-response-of-get-request/53738524?noredirect=1#comment94329935_53738524)
)

```
import requests
from json import loads
some_data = {'a':'',
             'b':''}

with requests.Session() as s:
    result = s.post('http://website.com',data=some_data)
    json_dict = loads(result.text)
    print([x["product_no"] for x in json_dict["list"]])
```

It is perfectly working on local PC(windows10), but now i'm working on AWS EC2 to run the code, however, it occurs error. 
The name of the file is timesale.py btw.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timesale.py", line 657, in <module>
    Timesale_Automation()
  File "timesale.py", line 397, in Timesale_Automation
    status_check()
  File "timesale.py", line 345, in status_check
    json_dict = loads(now_sale_page2.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I couldn't figure out why this error occurs.
I looked up overstackflow and there were some articles about decoding json but

```
result.text.decode('utf-8')
```

returns, I cannot decode str....

interestingly, I put print(result) between the codes and it is not 'None'
Why this would happen?

Comment: It looks like you didn't get a valid result. Can you try printing out `result.text` and `result.status_code`, that would give you a good idea of the actual response you're getting. Also why not just use `result.json()` instead of using `json.loads()`?

Comment: oh yes....it returns 200 status_code but the website that I want to parse is blocking the access....any idea how to deal with it? i put referer on each access headers...maybe location set of ec2 is foreign places? is it true? can I change that to locally? I'm living in south korea

Comment: have you tried just using `curl` to test if your EC2 setup is ok?

Comment: allright. the website is blocking me because aws server is located in USA which is foreign country. I will try to change the region or ip address to deal with it thank you for your help. it guided me to the light. Thanks!!

Comment: should be worth moving your ec2 instance to `Seoul (ap-northeast-2)` and then trying again.

Comment: I guess server(website) responds 40x or 50x status code to you. Can you check what request's difference between WIN10 and AWS, if they are same it maybe associate with connection(in this situation you should provide the url).